# How to synchronize my remote server and remote repository through PyCharm (and Git.)

Tags: git, pycharm, gitlab, remote-server

I'm looking for a person who know PyCharm's VCS feature(I will use Git) very well.

My project files are in remote server and I'm using Pycharm in my local PC to do remote work.

Now, my code files will upload from remote server to GitLab's Web repo 
and I want to synchronize my project in remote server with the GitLab's.

The problem is the repository my PyCharm controls is not my remote server's repository.

It is on my local PC.

In this case, my project in remote server can't be maintain same versions from GitLab.

I must work in remote server and use GitLab.

Is there anyone who have a idea to resolve my problem?
Please Help!

Comment: Why not add a new remote git repo on your local machine 'git remote add gitlab_remote HTTP://gitlab....'?

Comment: You mean this way : to pull project from Gitlab to local at first and push from local to remote server. Am I right? I think this is also good solution. But if I can, I want to sync from GitLab to remote server directly using PyCharm. I hope to this is not greed.